# Struct is being filled with zeros in C

Tags: c, global-variables

i have the following code:

.h file:

```
typedef struct subsystem
{
    const char* name;
    SDL_bool (*fun_init)();
    SDL_bool (*fun_updt)();
    SDL_bool (*fun_quit)();
    void (*fun_poll)(SDL_Event* event);
} subsystem_t;

subsystem_t audio_subsystem;
```

.c file:

```
SDL_bool audio_init()
{
    SDL_Log("Audio Init");
    return SDL_TRUE;
}

SDL_bool audio_quit()
{
    SDL_Log("Audio Quit");
    return SDL_TRUE;
}

subsystem_t audio_subsystem = {"Audio", audio_init, NULL, audio_quit, NULL};
```

When the program runs, audio_subsystem has the following data (with some log function):

(null) :: 00000000 :: 00000000 :: 00000000 :: 00000000

at runtime, name is NULL and all function pointers are NULL too, I don't know why it's happening, c compiler is filling my struct with zeros.

This is the log function:

```
SDL_Log("%s :: %p :: %p :: %p :: %p", subsystem->name, subsystem->fun_init, subsystem->fun_updt, subsystem->fun_quit, subsystem->fun_poll);
```

Edit:

> Adding extern keyword before subsystem_t audio_subsystem solved my
>   problem, i thought it was default lol. Thanks everyone who helped,
>   love you guys!

Comment: In the log function call you reference `system` and not `audio_subsystem`.  Possible name mismatch?

Comment: Put an `extern` in front of 'subsystem_t audio_subsystem' in your header file and it all should work.   Why GCC defaults to letting things like this link is beyond me, though.   `-fno_common` should be the default behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line in your header file:

```
subsystem_t audio_subsystem;
```

is not just a declaration, it is a definition of a static variable at file scope, which will be initialised with zero values. In addition, each compilation unit that includes the header will define its own `audio_subsystem`.

Apparently, your C file doesn't include its header, otherwise this line:

```
subsystem_t audio_subsystem = {"Audio", audio_init, NULL, audio_quit, NULL};
```

would be flagged a redefinition of the same symbol.

To fix your error, you could mark the variable in the header as declaration with the `extern` keyword:

```
extern subsystem_t audio_subsystem;
```

This just declares a variable without data. Users of your header file know that there is such a variable and the variable itself is defined (with proper initialisers) in your C file.

(But perhaps you can find a better design that doesn't require to share global variables. It is also good practice that C files should include their own headers to catch such mistakes.)

Comment: Not quite correct, the line that is found in the header is a declaration that is also a "tentative definition". So it is unfortunately not an error, even if the `.c` includes this header.